# Toshiba External Hard Drive freezes computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, external-hard-drive, toshiba-hard-drive

I bought a Toshiba Canvio Basics E05A032BAU2XK Portable External 320GB 2.5 Hard Drive: My computer has two OS's on it: Windows 7 and Windows XP. I need both. The main one I use is XP.

When booting my computer in any OS the computer and hard drive work fine. The same holds true for plugging in the hard drive while running Windows 7. However, when running WinXP, if the hard drive gets plugged in the computer freezes (my main point is that the HD is portable so it is essential that it does not do this, as I said I usually run XP).

After reading some online forums I was informed that there is a compatibility issue with the newest version of Eset Smart Security(I still don't understand this because it works fine in Windows 7 or when connected on boot...). I disabled the AV and plugged in the HD... Voila! The computer did not freeze.

However the disk is not recognized in explorer or disk management. In device manager I removed the device and did a scan and installation of device failed. It pretty much sounds like a driver issue but I cannot find any drivers for this HD. In fact, Toshiba claims that there are no downloadable drivers for it and that XP should take care of the drivers itself.

What to do? As far as I can tell, all other USB devices work just fine on both OS. Please Help!

Comment: Do you have any other usb devices connected when XP does not play nice with that drive? Try uninstalling eset completely, see if it works.